# Programmatically disabling the CDT builder on a programmatically created C project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm creating a C project programmatically using CDT:

```
    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();

    String projectName = projectNames[indices[i]];

    IProject newProjectHandle = root.getProject(projectName.replace("Examples_", ""));

    IProjectDescription description = workspace.newProjectDescription(newProjectHandle.getName());
    IProject project = CCorePlugin.getDefault().createCDTProject(description, newProjectHandle, new NullProgressMonitor());

    ICProjectDescriptionManager mngr = CoreModel.getDefault().getProjectDescriptionManager();
    ICProjectDescription des = mngr.createProjectDescription(project, false);
    ManagedProject mProj = new ManagedProject(des);


    Configuration cfg = new Configuration(mProj, null, projectName + ".id", projectName);
    cfg.setManagedBuildOn(false);
    IBuilder bld = cfg.getEditableBuilder();

    bld.setManagedBuildOn(false);
    bld.setAutoBuildEnable(false);


    CConfigurationData data = cfg.getConfigurationData();
    des.createConfiguration(ManagedBuildManager.CFG_DATA_PROVIDER_ID, data);


    mngr.setProjectDescription(project, des);
```

This works exactly as creating a makefile project from the C wizard.

What I want now is to programmatically untick the CDT builder from the project properties.

[image]

Is there any easy way to do this by adding a line or two to my project creation code?

Comment: Looking at the Builder property page `org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.internal.ui.BuilderPropertyPage` this is actually quite hard to do as it involves creating a disabled external tools launch configuration. Also disabling builders can lead to all sorts of strange behaviors.

Comment: Removing the builder from the property page also works my way. I don't need the CDT builder since I use others I import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok managed to change the code so that it creates the C projects without the builders:

```
            IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
            IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();

            String projectName = projectNames[indices[i]];

            IProject newProjectHandle = root.getProject(projectName.replace("Examples_", ""));

            newProjectHandle.create(new NullProgressMonitor());
            IProjectDescription description = workspace
                    .newProjectDescription(newProjectHandle.getName());

            newProjectHandle = CCorePlugin.getDefault().createCProject(description,
                    newProjectHandle, new NullProgressMonitor(),
                    ManagedBuilderCorePlugin.MANAGED_MAKE_PROJECT_ID);
            IndexerPreferences.set(newProjectHandle,
                    IndexerPreferences.KEY_INCLUDE_HEURISTICS, "true");
```